# Debugging 32 bit asp.net app in on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, 64-bit

On my development machine I am running IIS7 on Windows 7 64 bit and enabled "Enable 32-bit Applications" so i could use Ionic rewrite module. The problem is that under this configuration even though I attach to the right process my breakpoints will not get hit. Taking a closer look at the "Attach to Process" dialog I noticed that all other processes where running under x64 except the w3wp.exe that i am trying to debug. I reverted the "Enable 32-bit Applications" setting back to false and then my breakpoints work but my rewrite engine blows chucks because i am now in 64 bit mode. Does anyone have any ideas how to go about solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

With a little help from a friend i found that ionic rewrite did have a 64 bit download. Installed and works fine now.